# How do I create very large excel files from access database?

Tags: excel, ms-access, coldfusion

I have an issue right now where I believe my cold fusion code is trying to create a very large excel file after pulling records from an access database. I beleive it is timing out and giving a 500, null error. The cold fusion will need to process around 180,000+ records.  Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Here is pretty much how it goes down:

```
    <cfquery datasource="datasource" >
Drop Table Person
</cfquery> 

<cfquery datasource="datasource" >
Update1rowtble
</cfquery>


<cfset Clist=  "FNAME,LNAME,etc..">

<cfquery name="q" datasource="datasource" >
R2A</cfquery>



<cffile action="WRITE" file="filepath" output='#toString(queryToXL(Q,Clist))#' addnewline="No" fixnewline="No">

 <cfquery name="q" datasource="source" >
R3
</cfquery>

<cffile action="WRITE" file="filepath2" output='#toString(queryToXL(Q,Clist))#' addnewline="No" fixnewline="No">
```

Thanks

Comment: @tylercomp - Is MS Access actually the *source* of the 180K rows, or are you retrieving the data through a linked server (MS SQL)?

Comment: @tylercomp - Is this just a plain CSV file? It is not clear what the queryToXL() function does.

Comment: a .cfm file - I beleive that is what formats the information to be written to the excel file

Comment: @tylercomp - No, the file you are generating. You said Excel, but most likely it is just something that can be opened by Excel. Such as a CSV or html file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efficient is in the eye of the beholder.

If you are simply building a csv or html file that you are streaming to the browser as an xls file, then you need to make sure you write a row of data and flush the response buffer in order to keep the connection with the browser alive.

However, if you are building a giant excel file in memory and trying to send it down then you probably need to make some UI changes.

Namely, have the UI queue a request for the report/file.  Then let the browser go away and have the user come back later to check on it.  You could even have a little ajax thing check on the queue every so often.  For the server side of things, have a non-web process create the file and notify the queue when the job is complete.

Comment: You should look at the logs and find out what the 500 error is about. It sounds like more than just a simple timeout .. Perhaps the code is exhausting the available resources? So you may have to find a different way of doing things ;) I certainly hope you are not looping 180K times..

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to create a small VBscript function from inside the access database and perform the following code...

```
Sub example()
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "tableName", path
End Sub
```

you basically are able to export any table, to any excel file using the above statement...
if you have multiple tables that you want to add to the same sheet, just run the same command again on the same path and it will add the table to a different excel tab

Enjoy :)

Comment: Hope this doesn't expose my ignorance- but how would I kick this off from a coldfusion page?

Comment: @tylercomp

you wouldn't be able to from a coldfusion page. Really you would want to move to a more standard SQL database (mysql, sqlite) instead of Access (IMHO). Guess it doesn't really answer your question... But it is one way of doing it if you're able to gain access to the 'access' (pun unintended)

Answer (score 1):

If it is just a CSV file, you might also try an IN clause to INSERT the data directly into a file (from within the MS Access query).

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/in-clause-HA001231484.aspx

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20100611061207/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/access/archive/2009/03/27/accessing-external-data-using-the-in-clause.aspx)

You did not mention how frequently this export will happen. But 180K seems like a lot of records for Access. Given that it is a desktop database, I do not know how well it will handle an export of that size .. no matter how you slice it.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in mind what's been suggested, an additional help likely may be to export to a a csv and name it an .xls.  Most versions of excel handles that just fine.